# UIButton addTarget does not work

Tags: ios, uibutton

ViewController:

```
@implementation PaiLifeViewController
@synthesize detail = _detail;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_patcode_normal"];
    UIButton *c1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    c1.tag = 11;
    UIButton *c2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    c2.tag = 12;
    UIButton *c3 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    c3.tag = 13;
    UIButton *c4 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    c4.tag = 21;
    UIButton *c5 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    c5.tag = 22;
    UIButton *c6 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    c6.tag = 23;
    UIButton *c7 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    c7.tag = 31;
    UIButton *c8 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    c8.tag = 32;
    UIButton *c9 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    c9.tag = 33;

    [c1 setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c2 setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c3 setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c4 setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c5 setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c6 setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c7 setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c8 setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c9 setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSArray *c = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9, nil];
    _detail= [[PaiLifePageDetail alloc] initWithDataSource:c pageIndex:1];
    for (UIButton *b in c)
    {
        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:_detail];
}

- (void) clicked : (UIButton *) button
{
    NSLog(@"button = %i", button.tag);
}

@end
```

Custom View:

```
@implementation PaiLifePageDetail
#define MARGINTOTOP 120.0
#define MARGINTOLEFT 20.0
#define WIDTH 80.0
#define HEIGHT 60.0

- (id) initWithDataSource : (NSArray *) dataSource pageIndex : (int) pageIndex;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        if (dataSource)
        {
            for (UIButton *button in dataSource)
            {
                //page 1 line 1
                if (pageIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (button.tag == 11)
                    {
                        button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH * 2 + 20, HEIGHT);
                        [self addSubview:button];
                    }
                    else if (button.tag == 12)
                    {
                        button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + WIDTH * 2 + 20 * 2, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                        [self addSubview:button];
                    }
                }
                //not page 1 line 1
                else
                {
                    if ( button.tag == 11 )
                    {
                        button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                        [self addSubview:button];
                    }
                    else if ( button.tag == 12 )
                    {
                        button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + WIDTH + 20, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                        [self addSubview:button];
                    }
                    else if ( button.tag == 13 )
                    {
                        button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + (WIDTH + 20) * 2, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                        [self addSubview:button];
                    }
                }

                // line 2
                if ( button.tag == 21 )
                {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT, MARGINTOTOP + HEIGHT + 20, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:button];
                }
                else if ( button.tag == 22 )
                {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + WIDTH + 20, MARGINTOTOP + HEIGHT + 20, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:button];
                }
                else if ( button.tag == 23 )
                {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + (WIDTH + 20) * 2, MARGINTOTOP + HEIGHT + 20, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:button];
                }

                // line 3
                if ( button.tag == 31 )
                {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT, MARGINTOTOP + (HEIGHT + 20) * 2, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:button];
                }
                else if ( button.tag == 32 )
                {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + WIDTH + 20, MARGINTOTOP + (HEIGHT + 20) * 2, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:button];
                }
                else if ( button.tag == 33 )
                {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + (WIDTH + 20) * 2, MARGINTOTOP + (HEIGHT + 20) * 2, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:button];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

[image]

[image]

But when I click these buttons , they do not work at all , please help me with this, thank you very much.

Comment: have u check with breakpoint, did control in `for` loop entered?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes, it enter the loop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably a touch handeling event issue. I.e. the touches are never getting to you custom button.  To debug this:

1. What is your button's subclass?
2. Check userInterction enabled?
3. Check your superviews of the button for `UIGestureRecognizer` - they can interfere with touch handeling.
4. Is you clipsToBounds property NO? If so are the touches outside the bounds of the view?
5. Override the touchesBegan in your custom button to see if its being called.

Comment: What about the other points.  Have you added any gesture recognisers to the superviews?  Override touchesBegan and set a break point to see if its being called.  The more information the better.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I already had button below the superview of my button, for which I wanted to add target. I have changed the frame of my button., then the problem was solved

Comment: This was my problem. It was working, but the collision box was tiny.

Answer (score 0):

The method: `(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` is not used to create those PaiLifeCustomButton type buttons.

Or set a frame manually after calling init. I'vent looked much into your code but it all looks fine. Set breakpoints to see if your code runs or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,the problem is My view was creating with init instead of initWithFrame. Incase Anyone have same issue, then it may help you.